# What are the distinctive structural features of single- or double-stranded xRNA, or where can I find them?

Tags: rna, 3d-structure, nucleic-acids

I am interested in the structural differences caused by benzopurines and benzopyrimidines at the oligonucleotide level between RNA and xRNA, both in single-stranded and double-stranded form.

I am aware of RNA's tendency to be found in the A-form, of which the details are found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-DNA#Comparison_Geometries_of_the_Most_Common_DNA_Forms). However, other than the obvious nucleobase expansion, I can't seem to find any details about xRNA's secondary structure.

Answer (score 4):

The only paper I found that examined the question is ["Structural, Dynamical, and Electronic Transport Properties of Modified DNA Duplexes Containing Size-Expanded Nucleobases"](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp205122c). They state

> The results confirm that the structural and flexibility properties of
>   the canonical DNA are globally little affected by the presence of
>   benzo-fused bases. The most relevant differences are found in the
>   enhanced size of the grooves, and the reduction in the twist.

They also have a picture comparing the structures of conventional DNA and xDNA:

[image]

So while the basic structure seems similar, the difference in diameter and twist look rather large to me.

This is for xDNA, I would assume that xRNA behaves comparably if double-stranded. It would have to somehow fit the larger nucleobases into the helix like xDNA. And the structure of single-stranded RNA is variable, helical parts would probably look similar to xDNA, hard to say how the modified nucleobases would affect tertiary structure.